# Wpf RadDocking memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, telerik

I was tracking a problem of memory leak related to an event handler,while I've discovered that each time I open a raddoCking then I close it I got around 500kb of memory used and not released.
I'm using MVVM pattern and as far I've seen its not related to the mvvm library.

When I close a RadPane I set it context to null hasn't it enough?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call RadPane's RemoveFromParent() method for it to be garbage collected.

Please check out these links:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/radpanegroup-memory-leak

http://www.telerik.com/forums/radpane-not-garbage-collected-when-closed

Answer (score 0):

Few Points:

1. Setting RadPane's context to null isn't enough. You should unsubscribe from any event subscription to any long lasting objects and call Dispose for all disposable objects.
2. How do you measure memory? It would not release memory right after you close the RadPane. Garbage collection occurs only when it is required. If you want to test memory usage you should call GC collect and finalization before that.

   GC.Collect();

   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

However, if you want to track memory leaks accurately, you need to use a proper profiling tool which would show you growing objects and their retention graphs.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30855797/591656) for a good memory profiler.

Comment: I used dot memory from jetbrains. .. it tells me that around 500kb are taken between snapshots

Comment: @advapi: I guess, it does full garbage collection prior taking the snapshot. Does it show you what objects are growing? Have you disposed all disposable objects as I mentioned above? Do you experiece this memory growth consistantly for every open/close?

Comment: Hello I've done as you've told.. I see a memory grow each time I open close a RadPane...btw I've checked and I correctly call the RemoveFromPanel and set contents to null

Comment: @advapi: If you want to test memory leaks, you should be able to find which instance is growing and which instance holds the reference. It's quite difficult to guess and fix such issues. I would suggest you to try ANTS memory profiler. It has a trial period which would enough for you. Have  a look this this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673405/how-to-read-the-memory-snapshot-in-visual-studio/30855797#30855797