# Find non-[cycle detected] leaves in Paths to Root in Memory Snapshot

Tags: memory-leaks, visual-studio-2015, profiler

In VS2015 there is a useful tool for finding what is holding on to a reference to an object. However, in the spaghetti-like code that I am working in expanding this tree out has many leaves that end with [cycle detected] (e.g. A has a reference to B and B has a reference to A). For example:

[image: Tree with lots of cycles detected]

Is there a way to filter out the branches that contain just leaves with cycles? Or a way to export the data here?

Comment: I would like to see path to the root without WeakReferences.

Comment: I found something that might help. When you click on object (_mouse+right_) and choose **"View Instances"**, you can show all instances. Than you click on instance and show in "Path to Root" window that **only leaves not in cycle was expanded**. When you will pause the application and "Take shapshot" you can also show and inspect Value of that instances. [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673405/how-to-read-the-memory-snapshot-in-visual-studio)